# Is stdWrap.cache still working in v7.6/8.7?

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript

Tried to use stdWrap.cache on different instances (TYPO3 7.6.23 and 8.7.8) according to https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Functions/Cache/ But the content is rendered for each page instead of sharing it with other pages.

Also the exact example doesn't work:

```
page = PAGE
page.5 = TEXT
page.5 {
  stdWrap.cache.key = mycurrenttimestamp
  stdWrap.cache.tags = tag_a,tag_b,tag_c
  stdWrap.cache.lifetime = 3600
  stdWrap.data = date : U
  stdWrap.strftime = %H:%M:%S
}
```

Can anybody confirm this? Or does anybody currently have a working usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had been a documentation thing.

Caching has changed a little bit. You should use *cache* directly on your object - without *stdWrap*:

```
page = PAGE
page.5 = TEXT
page.5 {
  cache.key = mycurrenttimestamp
  cache.tags = tag_a,tag_b,tag_c
  cache.lifetime = 3600
  data = date : U
  strftime = %H:%M:%S
}
```

See https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82828